# Composer: create-project with specific commit

Tags: php, composer-php

Is it possible to create a project of specific commit by its hash? Something like `composer create-project composer/satis stais 004ef695d5`

I know how to specify version by tag or branch, but I cannot figure out how to point it to exact commit.

Answer (score -3):

> composer create-project composer/satis stais dev-master#004ef695d5

Comment: Don't use `<branch#ref>` syntax. It's not really supported by Composer. Referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42888045/1163786