# Pull latest commit with composer create-project

Tags: composer-php

I'd like to use `composer create-project` to always pull the latest commit of the dev version I'm using. I've noticed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600849/composer-create-project-with-specific-commit) exists but unfortunately it didn't help.

Currently I can do (e.g. for Drupal) `composer create-project drupal/drupal test 8.4.*@dev` but this will pull the nightly dev build. Instead, I'd like to be able to specify the commit hash I wish to pull from and thus ideally chase HEAD. Also, I'd like to do this with a one-liner if at all possible, without having to resort to a composer.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead, I'd like to be able to specify the commit hash I wish to pull from and thus ideally chase HEAD.

Well, there is a syntax to specify a git commit hash: `dev-master#hash` or `branch#hash`. But this feature is not really supported by the Composer team. It might not work as expected on the `create-project` command.
Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

If you want to "ideally chase HEAD", you can try to leave the third parameter on `create-project` away (You can provide a version as third argument, otherwise the latest version is used.).  Referencing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project

Maybe an alternative one-liner can help:

`composer require "vendor/project:dev-master#hash" && composer install`

Comment: "this feature is not really supported by the Composer team" <= this is probably the key element here. Probably better to use a workaround such as the one you recommend, because it doesn't seem supported indeed with the `create-project` command.